# STS intellisense stops working after some time

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have an i7 laptop with 16 GB of RAM. I'm working with SpringSource ToolSuite 4.8 and after some time of work, intellisense gets stuck and then never shows suggestions unless I restart it.

What can be done to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though Spring Tools 4.8 sounds like a relatively old version, maybe you are hitting this issue:

https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/750

It would be great if you could join the conversation for that issue on GitHub and provide more details in order to find out whether you are indeed hitting the same issue or not. Before you capture thread dumps, please make sure you update to the latest release (`4.14.0`).

To workaround this issue in the meantime in Eclipse, you can go to the `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content-Assist -> Advanced` and de-activate the `Language Server Proposals` in that list. In case my guesswork here is correct, that should workaround the issue.